# SVN errorcode=2 Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn, apache, macos

I've got MAMP running (XAMP for OSX), and I'm trying to setup subversion.

When I go to the freshly created repository in my browser, I get:

```
<D:error>
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

The repository is setup in ~/server/svn. My html/php files are also there (~/server/http), and it works fine. My basic httpd.conf setup:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNPath ~/server/svntest
(Authenticaton will be added later)
</Location>
```

I've allready chmod'ed everything to 777

```
drwxrwxrwx   9 gerrit  staff       306 27 okt  2008 svn
```

Apache's errorlog does not show any errors.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is ~/server/svntest? The web server doesn't normally have a home dir or even shell access, try substituting it for a full path.

Answer (score 5):

Try running

```
svnadmin verify ~/svntest/svn
```

on the repository. If that reports errors, run:

```
svnadmin recover ~/svntest/svn
```

Comment: It verifies. I'm not surprised, because its a fresh repostitory. I just created it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using SVNParentPath instead of SVNPath if you are pointing to a 
folder having multiple repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Change SELinux security context for repository files:

```
# chcon --reference=/var/www/html -R /var/svn/repos
# ll -Z /var/svn/repos
drwxr-xr-x  apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/svn/repos
```

Comment: I don't think this was the problem that Gerrit had, but it did solve my problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem and found it was caused by an incompatible version of SVNadmin and Apache. I had upgraded SVN on the machine (and forgotten that I had). I just used the full path (/usr/local/subversion-1.3.0/bin/svnadmin on my old CentOS machine) to the old svnadmin bin (version 1.3, as opposed to 1.6.11 which I had upgraded to). Then it worked immediately. No file permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

> ln -s /home/subversion/repos /var/www/html/

you should NOT do that... access for "everyone"... without svn, svn-user, ...

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
ln -s /home/subversion/repos /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

change permissions to `chown -R apache:apache /your repo`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is may be due to the port conflicts between virtual host and apache2.Check that once.That resolved the problem for me